# How to change bibliography locale in pandoc?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing, pandoc, markdown

I'm trying to render a document from MarkDown to PDF using pandoc:

```
pandoc my-document.md \
    --csl=citation-style.xml \
    --standalone \
    --smart \
    -V documentclass=report \
    -f markdown+footnotes+backtick_code_blocks+inline_notes+raw_html \
    --toc \
    --bibliography references.json \
    -V lang=pl-PL \
    -o my-document.pdf
```

The key here is the `lang=pl-PL` part: the document is written in Polish and targeted towards Polish audience.

The output contains proper Polish equivalents for "Table of Contents" and "Chapter" headers, but unfortunately the language used for bibliography is English.

How do I configure pandoc to apply Polish locale to bibliography as well?

Comment: many citation styles (in https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles) have hardcoded english locale (within the `style` tag, with the `default-locale` attribute as well as in style-specific `locale` tags). I tend to copy the styles and adjust them accordingly (something like the [chicago-fullnote-bibliography-fr](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/blob/master/chicago-fullnote-bibliography-fr.csl) style). You can always rely on biblatex for that, but you would have to create a `.tex` file and compile it by yourself.

Comment: pandoc does not call `bibtex` or `biber` to process bibliographies, it always relies on `pandoc-citeproc` and csl styles to do that. If my suggestion solves your problem, I think it's not TeX-related but exclusively related to pandoc and that you could get more help at [pandoc-discuss](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/pandoc-discuss).

Comment: @henrique unfortunately that does not seem to be the case with me. The citation style file does not contain `deafult-locale` attribute :(

Comment: @henrique I will check that discussion group, thanks!

Comment: You can add a `default-locale="pl-PL"` attribute to the `style` tag, even if there isn't one. BTW I don't think `-V lang=pl-PL` works, I think you should use `-V lang=polish` instead. Do you agree your question is not TeX-related? Should we close it?

Comment: changing the parameter to `-V lang=polish` unfortunately results with `! Package babel Error: You haven't specified a language option.` error for me :(
Adding the `default-locale="pl-PL"` helped - thank you!

Comment: I saw so many pandoc questions here, I assumed it's covered by this stack-echange's theme. Please close this question if it's not

Comment: Oh, sorry, I have an old version of pandoc here :P... Not every pandoc question is off-topic because many of them deal with latex packages and such, but not this one. I meant to close it only because it's strictly related to `pandoc-citeproc`...